# Perl read a large file for use with multi line regex

Tags: regex, perl, large-files

I have a 4GB text file with highly variable length lines, this is only a sample file, production files will be much larger.  I need to read the file and apply a multi line regex.

What is the best way to read such a large file for the multi line regex?

If I read it line by line, I don't think my multi line regex will work correctly.  When I use the read function in 3 argument form my regex results vary as I change the size of length I specify in the the read statement. I believe that the file's size makes it too large to be read into an array or into memory.

Here is my code

```
package main;
use strict;
use warnings;

our $VERSION = 1.01;
my $buffer;
my $INFILE;
my $OUTFILE;

open $INFILE, '<', ... or die "Bad Input File: $!";
open $OUTFILE, '>',... or die "Bad Output File: $!";

while ( read $INFILE, $buffer, 512  ) {
    if ($buffer =~ /(?m)(^[^\r\n]*\R+){1}^(B|BREAK|C|CLOSE|D|DO(?! NOT)|E|ELSE|F|FOR|G|GOTO|H|HALT|HANG|I|IF|J|JOB|K|KILL|L|LOCK|M|MERGE|N|O|OPEN|Q|QUIT|R|READ|S|SET|TC|TRE|TRO|TS|U|USE|V|VIEW|W|WRITE|X|XECUTE)( |:).*[^\r\n]/) {
        print $OUTFILE $&;
        print $OUTFILE "\n";
    }
}

close( $INFILE ); 
close( $OUTFILE );
1;
```

Here is some sample data:

```
^%Z("EUD")
S %L=%LO,%N="E1"
^%Z("RT")
This is data that I don't want the regex to find
^%Z("EXY")
X ^%Z("EW2"),^%Z("ELONG"):$L(%L)>245 S %N="E1" Q:$L(%L)>255  X ^%ZOSF("EON") S DX=0,DY=%EY,X=%RM+1 X ^%ZOSF("RM"),XY K %EX,%EY,%E1,%E2,DX,DY,%N Q
^%Z("F12")
S %A=$P(^DIC(9.8,0),"^",3)+1,%C=$P(^(0),"^",4)+1 X "F %=0:0 Q:'$D(^DIC(9.8,%A,0))  S %A=%A+1" S $P(^DIC(9.8,0),"^",3,4)=%A_"^"_%C,^DIC(9.8,%A,0)=%X_"^R",^DIC(9.8,"B",%X,%A)=""
^%Z("F2")
S %=$H>21549+$H-.1,%Y=%\365.25+141,%=%#365.25\1,%D=%+306#(%Y#4=0+365)#153#61#31+1,%M=%-%D\29+1,%DT=%Y_"00"+%M_"00"+%D,%D=%M_"/"_%D_"/"_$E(%Y,2,3)
```

The lines above are paired, syntactically (line 1 and 2 go together, 3 and 4, etc).  I need to find specific pairs, in the above data that's all of the pairs except for:

```
^%Z("RT")
This is data that I don't want the regex to find
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to parse a DSL (doman specific language) using a multi-line regex. This is almost always a terrible idea as the format can vary widely.  This appears to be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) and you've gone down the rabbit hole of thinking regex is the correct tool here when it is almost certainly not.  What you should do is [edit] your question to include a representative sample of the input, along with a description of your ultimate objective.

Comment: Because it looks complex enough for later extending and more precise parsing i would recommend to build a parser using [Pegex](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Pegex/lib/Pegex.pod). It is a bit steeper to start (need learn the Pegex and write the grammar-rules) but it could pay itself later...

Answer (score 3):

The question is apparently about parsing a [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), and it seems that in general regex isn't the right tool for that. A quick search did not yield an easy list of accepted approaches, except for [pages of CPAN modules](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=DSL&mode=all) and posts like [this article](http://blogs.perl.org/users/jeffrey_kegler/2012/08/domain-specific-languages-made-simpler.html). Finding out the best approach is indeed the first step.

However, below is an answer to the question as stated in the title and in the clear description: how to parse a very large file where units to be processed  spread over an unknown number of lines.

---

Keep assembling a 'buffer' and checking it.  Once you find a match, process and clear it.

For instance, appeand a line to a variable and check (try to match if you use regex). Keep going and once it does match process and clear the variable.

```
my $unit;
while (<$fh>) {
    # chomp;            # if suitable, and then add a space
    # $unit .= ' '.$_;  # as a separator that newline was
    $unit .= $_;

    if ( test_unit($unit) ) {
         # process ...
         $unit = undef;
    }
}
```

The `test_unit()` sub is a placeholder for code that would decide whether the assembled unit should be processed. If that is regex it can be defined before the loop, `my $re = qr/.../;` (see [qr in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)), and then test in the loop with `if ($unit =~ $re)`

A note in the question states that lines to be processed come in pairs, but it is clarificated in a comment that subsequent lines don't always pair up. Thus we can't process pairs of lines.

Comment: The paired syntax is not consistent, there are other data structures contained within the file.  The regex finds the multi line pairs I need and passes over all the other stuff so I need to avoid manipulating the data in case I disrupt the arcane structure of the data.  Could you suggest a code snippet of the buffer approach?

Comment: @Intrinsic I see. Then keep patching lines and checking. That way you only have (presumably) small chunks in memory at a time and you do exactly what you want, as I understand it.  (Unless the whole approach can be replaced by something else, as [@Jim Garrison](http://stackoverflow.com/users/18157/jim-garrison)'s comment says. I don't know that. I am responding to the title and the clear statement in the question.)

Comment: @Intrinsic  Updated to your clarification and to statements in other comments.

Comment: @Intrinsic  Great :)  If any questions pop up please let me know.