# Do grammar subparse on a file

Tags: grammar, raku

Let's say you only want to parse the start of a large file using Perl 6 grammar. In order to avoid reading the whole file into a string, and then call [`subparse`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Grammar#method_subparse) on the string. Is it possible to do a subparse when reading the file?

I could not find any `subparsefile()` method in the `Grammar` class, so I guess this is difficult to implement. But it should be possible in theory, see for example [How do I search a file for a multiline pattern without reading the whole file into memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42957583/2173773)

Comment: Should the match be anchored to the beginning of the file?

Comment: @EugeneBarsky Yes it should be anchored to the beginning, or alternatively, anchored so close to the beginning that it would pay off not to read the whole file into memory.

Comment: So the `rotor` part of the solution isn't needed in that case?

Comment: In that case, `"textfile".IO.lines.head(N).join.subparse($grammar)` should do the truck, where `N` is the number of lines to be read to ensure a possible match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently you can't.  Parsing anything at the moment requires the entire string to exist in memory.

Having said that, if you know the maximum number of lines your pattern may expand over, you could do something like:

```
my $max = 3; # maximum number of lines
for "textfile".IO.lines(:!chomp).rotor( $max => -$max + 1 ) -> @lines {
    @lines.join.subparse( $grammar)
    # and whatever you would like to do
}
```

It wouldn't be the fastest way of doing it, but it would not have to read the whole file in memory.

Comment: Alternately, if you know how many characters your pattern can be maximally, you might want to try a `"textfile".IO.comb(halfmaxsize).rotor(2=>-1) -> @chunks { @chunks.join.subparse($grammar) }`